# How do you route multiple apps in Flask Blueprints correctly?

Tags: python, flask

I have just rearranged my flask site to support multiple apps, but seems to have issues with the blueprinting and routing with multiple apps. The below runs, but when you goto localhost/backstory, the index rendered is the home index as opposed to the backstory index. I tried doing a few things like using the prefix_url in the blueprint registration, but that doesn't seem to work.

From what I can see, the Blueprint() function is pointing to right directory and should reference the index in the right folder for the route /backstory. Yet, it's not doing that. What am I missing?

```
from flask import Flask
from database import database

# blueprint import
from apps.home.views import home_blueprint
from apps.backstory.views import backstory_blueprint

application = Flask(__name__)

# setup with the configuration provided
application.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')

# setup all our dependencies
database.init_app(application)

# register blueprint
application.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)
application.register_blueprint(backstory_blueprint)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

**Home**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, flash

home_blueprint = Blueprint('home', __name__, template_folder="templates/home")


@home_blueprint.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**Backstory**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, flash

backstory_blueprint = Blueprint('backstory', __name__, template_folder="templates/backstory")


@backstory_blueprint.route("/backstory")
def backstory():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**Structure**

```
Project
 apps
  backstory
   templates
    backstory
      index.html
    views.py
  home
   templates
    home
      index.html
    views.py
 application.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong templates_folder location it seems. Should have pointed it to the templates and then did backstory/index.html as the render_template() location per the documentation on Flask.

> And then when you want to render the template, use admin/index.html as
> the name to look up the template by. If you encounter problems loading
> the correct templates enable the EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING config
> variable which will instruct Flask to print out the steps it goes
> through to locate templates on every render_template call.

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, flash

backstory_blueprint = Blueprint('backstory', __name__, template_folder="templates")


@backstory_blueprint.route("/backstory")
def backstory():
    return render_template('backstory/index.html')
```